# Use URL Rewrite as well as $_GET parameters in URL?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

OK so I already have a rewrite setup for my website that rewrites `/browse/blah` to `browse.php?location=blah`.

I would also like to pass another parameter that isn't rewritten. I know I can pass multiple parameters in a rewrite but I would like the URL to look like `/browse/blah?page=1`, and when a user visits this page it passes both the location and page parameters to `browse.php`.

Is this possible? Obviously I have tried it and it doesn't work so either it's not possible or there's something I have to do in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer if anyone else needs it.

The line I had the browse rewrite on in .htaccess just had [L] at the end, you need to change it to [QSA,L] (Query String Append)